# nl add numbers suffix if regex match?

Tags: nl

If I have a text file saying this:

```
Xgrep () { something ; }  

Xgrep
Xgrep
Xgrep
Xgrep
Xgrep
```

I want it to look like this

```
Xgrep () { something ; }  

Xgrep 12
Xgrep 13
Xgrep 14
Xgrep 15
Xgrep 16
```

Meaning I want to choose at which number to begin, with suffixes instead of prefixes with one space between (`-s " "` for a space between). I thought that I could use `nl` for this, but reading the man page it doesn't seem so. I tried this:

```
nl -b pexpr=Xgrep -s " " ~/desktop/test.txt
```

However this just out put this:

```
    Xgrep
    Xgrep
    Xgrep
    Xgrep
    Xgrep
```

Which is probably because the regex syntax is wrong but I couldn't find a way for it to match, all other ways it just listed the usage.

[This website](http://textmechanic.com/Number-Each-Line.html) is pretty much exactly what I am trying to do, but in command line form and only with numbers suffix.

Comment: The syntax for the BRE match would be something like `nl -b p'^Xgrep$' file` or `nl --body-numbering=p'^Xgrep$' file` I think. However, I don't know that `nl` allows either RH placement (as opposed to right *justification*) or provision of a specific start index. If you aren't stuck on `nl` you could use something like `awk -vi=12 '/^Xgrep$/ {$(NF+1)=i++}1' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% perl -ple 'BEGIN{$i=12} s/^(Xgrep)\s*$/"$1 ".$i++/e' < in
Xgrep () blah

Xgrep 12
Xgrep 13
Xgrep 14
Xgrep 15
Xgrep 16
Xgrep 17
%
```

Print lines, BEGIN the counter, match Xgrep and tack the incremented number onto the end. Replace `< in` with filename and add `-i` flag to clobber file in-place, if desired. An `awk` solution will likely look very similar.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but can I make the line to begin at a variable?